# reactjs setInterval doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactJS.

I'm trying to attached time on my web page. But, when I use `setInterval` the time doesn't work. Just stops at the current time when the page loaded.

I'm using React.createClass:

```
var MainContent = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {waktu: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}
  },

 componentDidMount: function(){
   setInterval(this.tick, 1000)
 }, 

 tick: function(){
    this.setState({waktu: this.state.waktu})
 },

  render: function(){

    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className="panel panel-success">
          <div className="panel-heading">
            <h3 className="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="panel-body">
            Panel content &nbsp;
            {this.state.waktu}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: I would guess that `waktu: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()` is only executed when defined. You need to return a function that gets a new date for you or call getInitialState inside the timeout

Comment: ^ yes. The current code is just updating with the same time every tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull your initial time code into a separate function and call that whenever you `setState`.

```
function getTime() {
  return new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
}

getInitialState: function() {
  return { waktu: getTime() }
}

tick: function() {
  this.setState({ waktu: getTime() })
}
```

You do also need to bind the function in your setInterval.

Comment: I got an error on function getTime said "Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , ".

Comment: getTime: function(){
  return new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
}, and it's working. Thank you :)

Comment: I was saying the ```getTime ``` function should be outside of your component. But it also works as a component method, you'd just need to call it with ```this.getTime()``` instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind this to your setTimeOut function you could see more about it here : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

```
setInterval(this.tick, 1000).bind(this)
```

and for change your date just apply a new date to your state:

```
this.setState({waktu: new Date()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the state to its own value after each interval wont help. You need to set to a current time

```js
var MainContent = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {waktu: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}
  },

 componentDidMount: function(){
       setInterval(this.tick, 1000)
     }, 
     currentTime: function () {
        return new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
     },
     tick: function(){
        this.setState({waktu: this.currentTime()})
     },


  render: function(){

    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className="panel panel-success">
          <div className="panel-heading">
            <h3 className="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="panel-body">
            Panel content &nbsp;
            {this.state.waktu}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<MainContent/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```